# Array of Objects to Objects with Modifications

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

#### Hi,

**Question:** How could I transform this:

```js
 console.log(prepararCoordenadas([
    { "nome": "Salvador",       "coordenadas": ["-23.6821604","-46.8754915"]},
    { "nome": "Brasília",  "coordenadas": ["-22.9137531","-73.5860657"]},
    { "nome": "Recife",          "coordenadas": [ "-8.0462741","-35.0000824"]}
  ]));
```

**on this ?**

```js
{ 
  '0':
   { nome: 'Salvador',
     coordenadas: [-46.8755, -23.6822 ] },
  '1':
   { nome: 'Brasília',
     coordenadas: [-73.5861, -22.9137] },
  '2': { nome: 'Recife', 
          coordenadas: [-35.0001, -8.0463] }
}
```

### Diff between the two results.

**First**
- is a array of object
- Have the name of the city and a array of "coordenadas" like string.

**Second**
- is a complete object
- Have the name of the city (same the first one) and a array of "coordenadas" like decimal with 4 numbers after dot;
-  Latitude and longitude are changed - position - *first longitude*;

**Language:** Javascript

I tried to use the ** Object.assign ** but lacked the changes with the "coordenadas".

```js
function prepararCoordenadas(array){

    let obj = Object.assign({},array);

    return obj;
  }

  // Test
  console.log(prepararCoordenadas([
    { "nome": "Salvador",       "coordenadas": ["-23.6821604","-46.8754915"]},
    { "nome": "Brasília",  "coordenadas": ["-22.9137531","-73.5860657"]},
    { "nome": "Recife",          "coordenadas": [ "-8.0462741","-35.0000824"]}
  ]));
```

Could any one help with this puzzle function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `reduce` into an object and transform the `coordenadas` with each iteration:

```js
const strToFixed4 = str => Number(str).toFixed(4);
const prepararCoordenadas = (array) => array.reduce(
  (accum, { nome, coordenadas: [lat, lng] }, i) => (
    {
      ...accum,
      [i]: { nome, coordenadas: [strToFixed4(lng), strToFixed4(lat)] }
    }),
  {}
);

console.log(prepararCoordenadas([
  { "nome": "Salvador",       "coordenadas": ["-23.6821604","-46.8754915"]},
  { "nome": "Brasília",  "coordenadas": ["-22.9137531","-73.5860657"]},
  { "nome": "Recife",          "coordenadas": [ "-8.0462741","-35.0000824"]}
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function prepararCoordenadas(array){
    let objs = {...array}; //es6 spread operator
    for (index in objs) { //for each object in objs
        objs[index].coordenadas.forEach(coordenada => Number(coordenada)); //for each coordenada in coordenadas array, convert type to number
    }
    return objs;
  }
```

The es6 spread operator in this case practically does the same thing as object.assign(), however, it has a far more simpler syntax.

I think creates the desired result, if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: ThankU! Only one thing, how can I interchange the "cordenadas" ? Longitude to latitude position.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer Guys! Thank U Two!

```js
const prepararCoordenadas = (array) => array.reduce(
  (accum, { nome, coordenadas: [lat, lng] }, i) => (
    {
      ...accum,
      [i]: { nome, coordenadas: [Number(parseFloat(lng).toFixed(4)), Number(parseFloat(lat).toFixed(4))] }
    }),
  {}
);

console.log(prepararCoordenadas([
  { "nome": "São Paulo",       "coordenadas": ["-23.6821604","-46.8754915"]},
  { "nome": "Rio de Janeiro",  "coordenadas": ["-22.9137531","-73.5860657"]},
  { "nome": "Recife",          "coordenadas": [ "-8.0462741","-35.0000824"]}
]));
```